# Different c++ compiler behavior when looking for overloaded vs. templated functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

I have been learning templates and trying to do some programming with it. Recently, I stumbled on a strange behavior which I try to summarize here. Suppose we have the following header file MyHeader.H

```
class Dit{...};
class B{...};
class A{
   ...
   B & operator[] (Dit & it){...};
   ...
 };

template <T> bar(T& t){

static_assert(!std::is_same(T,A)::value," in bar, T cannot be of type A");
...
};
```

and a main function

```
include "MyHeader.H"
foo(B & b){...};
foo(int t){...};
int main() {
    A a;
    Dit it;
    foo(a[it]); // the compiler has no problem in selecting the right overloaded foo
    bar(a[it]); // the compiler tries to instantiated it with type A, and because of the static_assert, it fails.
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler looks for a `bar(A a)` definition, given that `a[it]` is of type `B`? I have not tried it yet, but would it make a difference if I used

```
bar<B>(a[it]);
```

instead? Of course, if I do

```
B & temp=a[it];
bar(temp);
```

everything compiles fine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I don't get a `static_assert` meaning that it is taken as type B.

Comment: This, clearly, isn't your code: `template <T>` is wrong; no return type for functions; `operator[]` is `private`; `std::is_same(T,A)` is wrong (`<>`, no `()`). So, please, prepare a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually PW is right, and yes, this was just meant to be an sketch of the actual code. However, I am not sure why it was not compiling yesterday but today it behaves as expected. In the future, I will make sure that the skeleton code posted is actually correct.